# Сериализация и десериализация двусвязного списка

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток, господа программисты! Имеется у меня задание написать функции сериализации и десериализации двусвязног списка, а поскольку я столкнулся с этим впервые, несовсем понимаю как все это дело должно выглядеть.У кого какие соображения по этому поводу? Может какие-то примеры или статейки можете посоветовать буду очень рад)))

Примечание: сериализация подразумевает сохранение и восстановление полной структуры списка, включая взаимное соотношение его элементов между собой

Comment: Давайте начнём с простого: а элементы списка как вы сериализуете? Вы пользуетесь каким-то фреймворком, или вручную?

Answer (score 2):

Для начала прочтите, что такое сериализация, например [здесь](http://procplusplus.blogspot.ru/2012/12/c.html)

В вашем случае, т.к. это лабораторная, а не реальный проект, я бы поступил просто (если конечно в лабораторной нет никаких оговорок) - берете  последовательно данные из списка и отправляете в файл, через пробел например. 
При десириализации создаете список, последовательно читаете из файла и добавляете в список.

Comment: прочитал, но вся проблема в том что нужно все это своими руками сделать, а я не знаю даже с какой стороны ко всему этому делу подступить

Comment: @Uchiha1992, Вам же @nanotexnik явно сказал (только кратко):

последовательно проходите список от начала и пишете в файл данные, которые хранятся в элементах списка (естественно, без указателей).

Для десериализации читаете эти данные из файла и для каждой порции создаете элемент списка и вставляете его в хвост нового списка.

Comment: это то понятно... но что если у меня этих элементов будет большое количество? банальным циклом я тут не обойдусь

Comment: // сериализация
    {
    std::ofstream f("_test.txt", std::ios::out);
    std::copy(lst1.begin(), lst1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<A>(f, " "));
    }

    // десериализация
    std::list<A> lst2;
    {
    std::ifstream f("_test.txt", std::ios::in);
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<A>(f), std::istream_iterator<A>(), std::back_inserter(lst2));
    }
вот так сойдет?

Comment: @Uchiha1992, "но что если у меня этих элементов будет большое количество? банальным циклом я тут не обойдусь" -- цикл все стерпит.

Comment: стерпит то стерпит, только производительность тогда упадет

Comment: >стерпит то стерпит, только производительность тогда упадет

большое количество - это сколько? (особенно с учетом того, что речь идет о лабораторной работе) Сто штук? Тысяча? Пять тысяч? Или вам задают лабораторные, где требуется запись в файл миллиарда элементов? Крайне сомнительно.

Comment: @Uchiha1992, я вам расскажу страшную вещь - вы иначе как циклом по всем записям не пройдете.

Comment: @Fike ну можно наверное каким-нибудь **memcpy** это сделать тащемта

Comment: @DreamChild, **memcpy** ***по связному списку?***

Да и *внутри* `memcpy` все равно цикл. Чудес не бывает.

Comment: @Uchiha1992, 


     вот так сойдет?

Безусловно нет. При сериализации Вы теряете информацию о разбиении списка на элементы.